# Failed to resolve: firebase-common

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error when trying to add firebase auth

> Failed to resolve: firebase-common

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
...
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
 // Add to the bottom of the file - this is for Google Firebase
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything seems to work until I add the implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using firebaseui version 4.0.0, then it needs to be compatible with the firebase libraries versions also.

The version 4.0.0, FirebaseUI has the following dependency versions:

```
     Library        Version
firebase-auth       16.0.1
play-services-auth  15.0.1
firebase-database   16.0.1
firebase-firestore  17.0.1
firebase-storage    16.0.1
```

more info here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries

Also upgrade:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
```

to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
```

check this:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: If I do this I get another error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzxl
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzxl, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: what version of google service plugin are u using? Use this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in the top level gradle file

Comment: (which is why I have not updated the implementations)

Comment: I am using classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' and  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

Comment: Use this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in the top level gradle file

Comment: Then I get this error: `Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.4,15.0.4], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: did you update the firebase libraries according to the release notes?

Comment: update all your firebase libraries according to the versions here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android, and use google-services 4.0.1, I think the problem is from firestore, be sure to update it to 17.0.2 as in the link

Comment: Thank you, I missed to change one (firebase-invites)