# The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when updating the Firebase libraries:

> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested
>   by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,16.0.0), [16.0.1,16.0.1],
>   [16.0.1,99999]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check
>   your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Dependencies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
```

Is there a simple way to find the correct configuration?
If not, what plugin is to be disabled and how? if i just run the task i get the same error.

**Update:**
 i think this dependency has something to do it with, because if disable it's pluging the depedency task runs:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003691/failed-to-resolve-firebase-common)

Comment: Aligning to that versions still don't fix. I use other libraries that also bind to older version.

Comment: Do you use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1`? (In your project build.gradle file)

Comment: It works if updating classpath as well. if you want to post as answer i will accept it.

Comment: All dependencies are now at the latest version, no issues at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using these steps:

- Update your implementation versions (for the newest firebase versions see the release notes https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)
- Update your project build.gradle file with the newest google-services version (at the moment `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1`)

Or see [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003691/failed-to-resolve-firebase-common)